# mysql transaction timeout and connection heartbeat when crash

Tags: mysql, crash

My problem is: Assume process-A have a mysql client and start a transaction. Before process-A commit or rollback, it cause OOM or net-wire is nipped by someone. How would mysql server deal with it (under two condition above)?

I know the default transaction timeout on innodb engine is 50 second, and mysql client have a connection pool here. I guess the connection pool have it's own heart beat, and mysql server would consider client is shutdown if no heartbeat is received.

Can you tell me, what exactly will happen and give the reference of it? Version is `10.1.29-MariaDB-6ubuntu2 Ubuntu 18.10`

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer this by myself. Have a look at [net_read_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_read_timeout), there is default 30 seconds before server regard client as shutdown, and cancel the transaction. To me, by using go-sql-driver, it's recommended to [setup this variable](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/#readtimeout) when open a DB client if want custom.

I still don't know the detail of server-client protocol, is there a heartbeat or just TCP keep alive? Waits for more diving.